# How to distribute questions across sections in a LaTeX template?

Tags: r-exams

The exam I am planning to write has several sections. Is it possible to distribute the questions by the respective sections while using a LaTeX template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but then you need to hard-code the number of questions. Other than that it is very straightforward. Rather than putting a single placeholder into the LaTeX template:

```
%% \exinput{exercises}
```

you need to input the exact exercise files, e.g.,

```
\section{Quiz questions}

\begin{enumerate}

\input{exercise1.tex}

\input{exercise2.tex}

\end{enumerate}


\section{Practical exercises}

\begin{enumerate}

\input{exercise3.tex}

\input{exercise4.tex}

\end{enumerate}
```

This gives you full control over how and where the exercises are included. More details are given in Section 3 of `vignette("exams", package = "exams")`.

*Caveat:* Leading zeros are added in the exercise number if there is more than one digit in the number of exercises, e.g., `exercise01.tex` if there are between ten and 99 exercises.

Comment: Thanks, Achim! The suggested approach does not allow for randomization of the order of the exercises within each section. However, that can be achieved by creating a template generator, as you advised when replying to my other question.

Comment: The randomization of the order of the questions is orthogonal to the sectioning. So if you have four exercise files A-D, you could set up a list with two elements (corresponding to the sections) and two exercises each: `exm <- list(c("A.Rmd", "B.Rmd"), c("C.Rmd", "D.Rmd"))`. And then you can sample two exercises without replacement from each section which means that you permute the order of the questions within each section: `exams2pdf(exm, nsamp = c(2, 2), ...)`. This can be combined with the template with sections above but also with standard templates.

Comment: Thanks, Achim! That is perfect!